Wordpress AJAX bad request 400
I've been trying to create an AJAX function for my custom WordPress theme. It's supposed to fetch data of a custom post type and display it on a sidebar that pops up. I've separated the files; functions.php, main.js, sidebar.php. I just can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a bad request 400 response. This is the code in the function.php
function add_scripts_styles($hook) {
        wp_enqueue_script('my_js_file', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/main.js', array('jquery'), 1);
        wp_localize_script('my_js_file', 'ajax_details', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin.ajax.php'),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my_nonce'),
        ));
    }
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","add_scripts_styles");

function do_this(){
        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);

        ob_start();

        echo "Hello World";

        $out = ob_get_clean();
        $out = strtolower($out);

        var_dump($out);
    }

    add_action("wp_ajax_do_this","do_this");
    add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_do_this","do_this");

this the code in main.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=tagged]');
    function open(){
        document.querySelector('.sidebar').style.width = "25%";
    }

    function close(){
        document.querySelector('.sidebar').style.width = "0";
    }
    cards.forEach(card => {
        card.addEventListener('click', e => {
            open();
            var id_post = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-post_ID');
            console.log(id_post);

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: `${window.location.origin}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`,
                data:{
                    action: "my_action",
                    post_id: id_post,
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#pusha').html(result.data.html);
                }
            });
                        
        })
    })

    close();
})

and in sidebar.php
<?php
/*
Sidebar
*/
?>
<div class="sidebar">
  <button id="closed"><i class="fa fa-window-close" style="background-color: whitesmoke; color: black"></i></button>
  <div id="pusha">
    </div>
 <script>
  
  let cBtn =document.getElementById('closed');
  cBtn.addEventListener('click', e=> {
    document.querySelector('.sidebar').style.width = "0";
  })
 </script>
</div>

I expected to display the post data when the sidebar appears

if the answer is in json, it's more practical to create a new endpoint of the api : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/. and for using admin-ajax.php, if you have action = "my_action" then the hook to use is wp_ajax_my_action.

Alright then. Let me try that out. Thank you
